# Currency formatting in React

Tags: reactjs, currency-formatting, input-mask, react-number-format

I would like to create an input field that formats the value as follows

```
> The default value is 0.00
> 0.00, I press 2 and get 2.00
> 0.|00, I press 2 and get 0.20
> 0.0|0, I press 2 and get 0.02
```

So far, all of this works as expected, but when the user places the cursor like this 0|.00, presses 2. In that case, nothing happens I would like for it to become 2.00 but I can't achieve that because I needed to disallow leading zeros which I've done using the `isAllowed` prop. If I remove it, the zeros I type are gone after the input loses focus but I don't want to be able to write any leading zeros.

Any help is appreciated.

I use react-number-format and this is the current code I have

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    return (
        <NumericFormat
            value={value}
            decimalScale={2}
            decimalSeparator=","
            thousandSeparator="."
            suffix=" EUR"
            fixedDecimalScale
            isAllowed={(values) => {
                const {value, floatValue} = values;

                if (value.charAt(0) === '0') {
                    if (value.charAt(1) && value.charAt(1) !== '.') {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }}
            allowNegative={false}
            onValueChange={(values) => {
                const {formattedValue, value, floatValue} = values;
                console.log(values);

                if (value.charAt(0) !== '0' && value.charAt(1) === '0') {
                    console.log('split[0]', value.split('')[0]);
                    return setValue(+value.split('')[0]);
                }

                if (value.charAt(0) === '0' && value.charAt(1) !== '0') {
                    console.log('split[1]', value.split('')[1]);
                    const valueToSet = +value.split('')[1];
                    return setValue(!Number.isNaN(valueToSet) ? valueToSet : 0);
                }

                if (value === '') {
                    return setValue(0);
                }

                return setValue(floatValue!);
            }}
        />
```